# Using not described parameters in measurement protocol

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

Is a transfer of parameters `tel` and `email` that aren't part of Measurement Protocol and aren't described in [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters?hl=en), the identificational data upload ?

For example:

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?dh=example.com&cid=000000000.0000000000&ea=Trigger&ec=MyEventCategory&t=event&v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXX1-0&dp=index.html&tel=XXXXXXXXXXX&email=email@example.com
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: this question is quite clear as it is what exactly do you think needs updating?

Comment: Unknown parameters will be ignored. You could send custom dimensions, but as DalmTo pointed out that would violate TOS.

Answer (score 0):

you are not allowed to send user identifiable information to Google analytics like email or phone number.

> Caution: You may not upload any data that allows Google to personally identify an individual (such as names and email addresses), even in hashed form. See the Measurement Protocol Policy for more details.

please see [Measurement protocol email](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/email) and  [policy details](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/policy)

the only parameters you can send can be found in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en)